# Blank page response with successful form authentication on wildfly

Tags: jsf, forms-authentication

I'm aware similar sounding questions have been asked in the past. But this issue is really annoying me and I'm not sure if it can be resolved easily.
In order to cope with a successful login when the JSESSIONID cookie was missing or had expired, the web.xml was configured to redirect to the home page on a 408 error. This was when running on JBoss 7.1.1.

The login page is standard j_security_check form based authentication with POST action etc.

We then migrated to Wildfly 8.2.1, where we found that the server simply replies with 200 OK and so a blank page would be presented, with the url ending in xxx/j_security_check .
. Not nice since the user had logged in successfully.

The correct response was still being presented when trying to login with invalid credentials.

I tried running on wildfly 10.1 as well but no difference.
I'm guessing it's caused by a "fix" with undertow which requires some additional handling, possibly in a web filter.

Has anyone else experienced this issue and managed to find a solution?